# Como cargar una imagen de fondo en un Canvas Java

Tags: java, netbeans, canvas

¡Hola!

Necesito cargar la siguiente imagen en un Canvas que estoy utilizando

[image: Image para cargar en el canvas]

Este es el codigo el cual estoy cargando el canvas

```
public JFrameJuegoBase() {
        initComponents();
        canvas = new CanvasDibujable();
       canvas.setBounds(30,30,720,600);
       canvas.setBackground(Color.WHITE);    
        this.add(canvas);       
        cliente=new Cliente();      
    }
```

Actualmente asi tengo el panel al desplegar el proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Basicamente lo que necesito es colocar ese fondo pasto en el JPanel de mi aplicacion utilizando el Canvas

Agrego clase CanvasDibujable.java

```
public class CanvasDibujable extends JPanel implements Runnable{

    private ControladorTank controladorBola;

    public CanvasDibujable(){
        super();
        controladorBola=new ControladorTank();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            this.repaint();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics graphics){
        super.paint(graphics);
        getControladorBola().dibujarBola(graphics,
                getControladorBola().getBola());
        getControladorBola().dibujarBola(graphics,
                getControladorBola().getBola2());
    }

    /**
     * @return the controladorBola
     */
    public ControladorTank getControladorBola() {
        return controladorBola;
    }

    /**
     * @param controladorBola the controladorBola to set
     */
    public void setControladorBola(ControladorTank controladorBola) {
        this.controladorBola = controladorBola;
    }


}
```

Comment: Saludos, Sebastian, por favor agrega la clase `CanvasDibujable` en tu pregunta.

Comment: Revisa nuevamente la pregunta ya agregue la clase CanvasDibujable, Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

Saludos, Sebastian.

Para dibujar una imagen en un `JPanel` sobreescribe el método `paintComponent` y utiliza el método `drawImage` de esta manera:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(fondo, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
}
```

Donde `fondo` es la imagen que deseas dibujar. Esta imagen debes definirla en tu clase `CanvasDibujante` y cargarla en el constructor de dicha clase:

```
private ControladorTank controladorBola;
private BufferedImage fondo;

public CanvasDibujable(){
    super();
    controladorBola=new ControladorTank();

    try {
        this.fondo = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\fondo.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Controlar la excepcion si la imagen no se encuentra o no se pudo cargar
    }
}

// Aquí hay más código...
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

[image: gif]

Acá te adjunto la [documentación de Java para el método Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.Color,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver)) donde puedes encontrar más información sobre los métodos `drawImage`.

Y además, la imagen de fondo la puedes cargar de distintas formas, yo preferí usar la clase `ImageIO` esto queda a tu disposición. ;-).