# Java: Como agregar imágenes PNG en un Canvas

Tags: java, canvas, interfaz-gráfica

Esta vez tengo el siguiente problema necesita cambiar esta dos imágenes (bolas azules) que estan dibujadas dentro de un Canvas, por imágenes reales en formato PNG.

[image]

Las bolas azules las estoy dibujando de la siguiente manera

```
public class ControladorTank{
    private Bola bola;
    private Bola bola2;

    public ControladorTank(){
        bola=new Bola(30,30,170,175);
        bola2 = new Bola(30,30,170,30);
    }

    /**
     * @return the bola
     */
    public Bola getBola() {
        return bola;
    }

    /**
     * @param bola the bola to set
     */
    public void setBola(Bola bola) {
        this.bola = bola;
    }

    /**
     * @return the bola2
     */
    public Bola getBola2() {
        return bola2;
    }

    /**
     * @param bola2 the bola2 to set
     */
    public void setBola2(Bola bola2) {
        this.bola2 = bola2;
    }

    public void moverDerecha(JPanel panel,Bola bola){
        if(bola.getPosx()<panel.getWidth()-30){
            bola.setPosx(bola.getPosx()+5);
        }
    }

    public void moverIzquierda(Bola bola){
        if(bola.getPosx()>0){
            bola.setPosx(bola.getPosx()-5);
        }
    }

    public void moverArriba(Bola bola){
        if(bola.getPosy()>=5){
            bola.setPosy(bola.getPosy()-5);
        }
    }

    public void moverAbajo(JPanel panel,Bola bola){
        if(bola.getPosy()< panel.getHeight()-30){
            bola.setPosy(bola.getPosy()+5);
        }
    }

    public void dibujarBola(Graphics gui, Bola bola){
        gui.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        gui.fillOval(bola.getPosx(), bola.getPosy(),bola.getAncho(),bola.getAlto());
    }

}
```

Necesito cambiarlas por imagenes en PNG como por ejemplo las siguientes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agrego clase ControladorTank

```
public class ControladorTank{
    private Bola bola;
    private Bola bola2;

    public ControladorTank(){
        bola=new Bola(30,30,170,175);
        bola2 = new Bola(30,30,170,30);
    }

    /**
     * @return the bola
     */
    public Bola getBola() {
        return bola;
    }

    /**
     * @param bola the bola to set
     */
    public void setBola(Bola bola) {
        this.bola = bola;
    }

    /**
     * @return the bola2
     */
    public Bola getBola2() {
        return bola2;
    }

    /**
     * @param bola2 the bola2 to set
     */
    public void setBola2(Bola bola2) {
        this.bola2 = bola2;
    }

    public void moverDerecha(JPanel panel,Bola bola){
        if(bola.getPosx()<panel.getWidth()-30){
            bola.setPosx(bola.getPosx()+5);
        }
    }

    public void moverIzquierda(Bola bola){
        if(bola.getPosx()>0){
            bola.setPosx(bola.getPosx()-5);
        }
    }

    public void moverArriba(Bola bola){
        if(bola.getPosy()>=5){
            bola.setPosy(bola.getPosy()-5);
        }
    }

    public void moverAbajo(JPanel panel,Bola bola){
        if(bola.getPosy()< panel.getHeight()-30){
            bola.setPosy(bola.getPosy()+5);
        }
    }

    public void dibujarBola(Graphics gui, Bola bola){
        //gui.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        gui.drawImagen(bola.getImagen(), bola.getPosx(), bola.getPosy(), bola.getAncho(), bola.getAlto(), null);
    }
```

Comment: fijate si va por este lado: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17780170/1423096

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

Como indicó @alo Malbarez, podrías utilizar un `JLabel`, sin embargo, eso implicaría modificar el código que ya tienes (ya que deberías extender tu clase `Bola` de un `JLabel`, agregar los iconos, etc...).

En caso de que prefieras seguir utilizando el código así como lo tienes, entonces el procedimiento es similar al que te mencioné en la respuesta de acá: [Como cargar una imagen de fondo en un Canvas Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/155340/66587).

Necesitarías agregar un campo de imagen (como un `BufferedImage`) y su respectivo getter y setter (o bien, podrías crear el campo como `final` y cargar la imagen directamente desde el constructor justo como hiciste con el fondo).

En cuanto a cómo dibujar dicha imagen, debes modificar tu método `dibujarBola`, y realizar el mismo procedimiento que el fondo.

```
public void dibujarBola(Graphics gui, Bola bola) {
    gui.drawImagen(bola.getImagen(), bola.getPosx(), bola.getPosy(), bola.getAncho(), bola.getAlto(), null);
}
```

Como ves, se agregó el método `bola.getImagen();`, por lo que en tu clase `Bola` (que debería ahora llamarse `Tank` o `Tanque`), deberías también haberlos declarado:

```
public class Bola {
    // Aqui van tus variables
    private final BufferedImage imagen;

    public Bola() {
        try {
            // A modo de ejemplo, puse la imagen en el C:, sin embargo podrías agregarla a tu proyecto, o buscarla en otro directorio
            this.imagen = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\tanque.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Controlar la excepcion si la imagen no se encuentra o no se pudo cargar
        }
    }

    public BufferedImage getImagen() {
        return this.imagen;
    }
    // Aquí van más métodos...
}
```

**NOTA**

Al ver el camino que está tomando tu proyecto, y a modo de opinión, me parece que lo que estás pensando hacer es mover tu tanque según las teclas que presiones, toma en cuenta que al dibujar la imagen en tu `JPanel` (el cuál lo llamas `Canvas`) la imagen no se moverá según la dirección, si mueves hacia los lados, la imagen seguirá igual como la cargues, por lo que te recomiedo que busques información de cómo realizar un juego en 2D en Java. Ahí podría funcionarte leer sobre `AffineTransform` o bien, buscar otra técnica como cargar las imagenes según te muevas (eso implica tener varias imagenes que debes cargar)

Comment: Aun no me funciona estoy presentando problemas en la clase Bola y la clase ControladorTank

Comment: ¿qué problema estás presentando?

Comment: El constructor que yo agregué en el código es de ejemplo, solamente utiliza la parte del `try` (la imagen), e implementalo en tu código (tu constructor de `Bola`)

Comment: Continuemos el debate en el chat

Comment: Tengo problemas al colocar el `try` dentro del constructor

Comment: ¿De qué forma lo estás agregando en el constructor? o ¿Qué error te lanza?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76381/discussion-between-sebastian-salazar-and-c-rodriguez).