# ¿Se puede dentro de un contenedor con layouts acomodar los componentes en la posicion que uno quiera?

Tags: java

Por ejemplo:dentro de un panel con un `BorderLayout`,en la zona central quiero añadir una imagen y debajo de esa imagen un boton,como podria hacerlo para no tener que poner el boton en la zona sur del contenedor?

```
public Principal()  {
    this.iniciarVentana(this);
    this.setIcono(this);
    panel=new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());;
    this.add(panel);
    panel1=new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    panel.add(panel1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    label=new JLabel();
    label.setSize(500, 200);
    this.crearImagenLabel(label,"C:\\Users\\sf\\Desktop\\guillo.jpg");
    panel1.add(label); 
    botonConfiguracion=new JButton();
    this.botonConfiguracion.setBackground(Color.white);
    botonConfiguracion.setBorderPainted(false);;
    this.crearImagenBoton(botonConfiguracion, "C:\\Users\\sf\\Desktop\\configuracion.jpg");
    panel1.add(botonConfiguracion);
}
```

Lo que quiero lograr con ese codigo es tener un panel que se divida con un `BorderLayout`,en el centro de ese panel,con un `BorderLayout.CENTER` poner otro panel con una imagen y un boton.La idea es que la imagen quede centrada y el boton debajo, pero cuando los añado me aparece la imagen arriba de todo. Como puedo solucionarlo? Hay que usar otro tipo de *layout* o se puede reposicionar con algun metodo y las coordenadas que yo quiera dentro de ese panel?

Comment: Tienes una imagen o mock-up del resultado esperado que nos pueda ayudar a responder tu pregunta? Tienes código que hayas intentado? lo puedes compartir con nosotros? Qué has hecho y cuál ha sido el resultado?

Comment: ahi lo edite amigo

Comment: ¿Imagen de fondo? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/154805/como-cargar-una-imagen-de-fondo-en-un-canvas-java

Comment: No,el problema no es el la imagen,el tema es como hago para centrarla con un flowlayout,porque al correr el codigo me aparece arriba de todo y no en el centro